# How can I add more margin in the documentviewer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xtrareport, devexpress-mvc

I have a report and this is the code for my html page:

```
@Html.DevExpress().DocumentViewer(settings =>{
    // The following settings are required for a Report Viewer.
    settings.Name = "documentViewer1";
    settings.Report = (Misteryshopper.Reports.ResumenProyecto)ViewData["Report"];
    // Callback and export route values specify corresponding controllers and their actions.
    // These settings are required as well.    

    settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Report", Action = "ProyectDocumentViewerPartial" };
    settings.ExportRouteValues = new { Controller = "Report", Action = "ProyectExportDocumentViewer", ReportName = ReportName };
    // Parameters

    settings.SettingsReportViewer.EnableRequestParameters = false;
    settings.SettingsSplitter.SidePaneVisible = false;  

    }).GetHtml()
```

The problem is that in the browser I see my report document correctly, but I   can´t see the borders of my report correctly, I have attached an image for the view.

Is there any way to put more margin in the document viewer?

I have to stress that when I print my report, it seems good, the
problem is only in the preview document viewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add only this line in your code:

> settings.SettingsReportViewer.EnableMargins= true;

```
@Html.DevExpress().DocumentViewer(settings =>{
// The following settings are required for a Report Viewer.
settings.Name = "documentViewer1";
settings.Report = (Misteryshopper.Reports.ResumenProyecto)ViewData["Report"];
// Callback and export route values specify corresponding controllers and their actions.
// These settings are required as well.    

settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Report", Action = "ProyectDocumentViewerPartial" };
settings.ExportRouteValues = new { Controller = "Report", Action = "ProyectExportDocumentViewer", ReportName = ReportName };
// Parameters

settings.SettingsReportViewer.EnableRequestParameters = false;
settings.SettingsSplitter.SidePaneVisible = false; 

// YOU HAVE TO ADD THIS LINE ...... 
    settings.SettingsReportViewer.EnableMargins = true; 

    }).GetHtml()
```