# Hide side and toolbar panel in DevExpress.WebDocumentViewer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress, xtrareport

I have mvc component for displaying XtraReport. Code is like this:

```
@Html.DevExpress().WebDocumentViewer(settings =>
{
    settings.Name = "webDocumentViewer";
    settings.Height = 770;
    settings.ControlStyle.CssClass = "fullscreen"; 
}).Bind(Model.Report).GetHtml()
```

Now I need to hide toolbar and side panel with params. I don't want to show them to user.  How can I do this?

I saw post here: [kind of mine problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32819618/how-can-i-add-more-margin-in-the-documentviewer/32822223#32822223) 
but there is used another component - DocumentViewer and I need to use WebDocumentViewer

Comment: can you provide documentation link of this WebDocumentViewer thing on DevExpress??

Comment: [documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument114491)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, there is no params for hiding sidebar and toolbar.
You can use below css

```css
    .dxrd-preview .dxrd-right-panel-collapse, .dxrd-preview .dxrd-right-panel, .dxrd-preview .dxrd-right-tabs {
        display: none;
}
```

And use js to remove the menuitem on toolbar

```c#
    function OnCustomizeMenu(s, e) {
        var actionExportTo = e.Actions.filter(function (action) { return action.text === "Toggle Multipage Mode"; })[0]
        var index = e.Actions.indexOf(actionExportTo);
        e.Actions.splice(index, 1);
    }
    @Html.DevExpress().WebDocumentViewer(settings =>{
        settings.Name = "WebDocumentViewer";
        settings.ClientSideEvents.CustomizeMenuActions = "OnCustomizeMenu";
    }).Bind(new WebDocumentViewerCustomExportOptions.Models.XtraReport1()).GetHtml()
```

#### Reference

- [How to hide/remove right tabs on HTML5 Document Viewer](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T335445)
- [How to remove the multipage mode item from the WebDocumentViewer toolbar](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T339839)